# Node Express Response Cookie Value is Encoded

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set a cookie on the response using Express, but it's encoding the value. I'm setting a value with an equals sign, but on the client, it's coming through as %3D.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Argh, I found it!

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

encode option needs to be set to String.

Comment: This is the correct one, please mark this as correct.

Answer (score 5):

Express `req.cookie` method accepts the third param as config, you can set the encoding method for cookie value in it. By default it uses `encodeURLComponent`, so to prevent this, you can define a custom function to override it:

```
const myCookieEncode = function (val) {
    return val;
};

...

res.cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, { encode: myCookieEncode })
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's by default encoding into 'HTML URL encoding' So in URL every special character have a code and '=' has a code '%3D'. So it is simply converting into that code

You can read more from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: I don't think it will affect you anyways if you read it again in nodejs code then it will come with same data (I mean with = sign).
But Don't know how to stop it.